# Rails: change default JSON structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

I'm new in Rails and I use the version 4.2.0.

Let's suppose that we have the following JSON at the url localhost:3000/users

```
[{id: 1, "firstName": "John","lastName": "Smith"},
{id: 2, "firstName": "John","lastName": "Red"}]
```

but this is not what I want, I expect something like:

```
{ users :[
{id: 1, "firstName": "John","lastName": "Smith"},
{id: 2, "firstName": "John","lastName": "Red"}
]}
```

How can i do? Thanks everybody.

Comment: can you post the controller code for the user

Comment: class UserController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @users = User.all
      render json: { users: @users}
   end
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in users index controller

```
render json: {users: @users}
```

where

```
@users = [{id: 1, "firstName": "John","lastName": "Smith"},
          {id: 2, "firstName": "John","lastName": "Red"}]
```